# Crosstab/pivot query with different number of columns depending on a field

Tags: c#, mysql, pivot

I need to pivot my tables with a set of column headers that varies based on one of the fields in the output.

This is what it looks like currently:

```
id | Name | Test Name | Test Performed | Test Value
1    John     HIV         EIA            Reactive
1    John     HIV         EIA2           Reactive
1    John     HIV         WB             Positive
1    John     HIV         Final Kit      Positive
2    Mark     HIV         Rapid          Reactive
2    Mark     HIV         EIA            Reactive
2    Mark     HIV         EIA2           Reactive
2    Mark     HIV         Final Result   Positive
2    Mark     Immuno      CD4%           12.0%
2    Mark     Immuno      CD4 Lympo      1299
2    Mark     Immuni      CD4 Absolute   838
3    Carl     SY          RPR            Reactive
3.   Carl     SY          TPHA           Reactive
```

I want it to be like this, you can see the columns are changing dynamically based on Test Performed:

```
id | Name | Test Name | EIA      | EIA2   | Rapid |  WB         |Final Kit 
1    John    HIV        Reactive  Reactive           Positive
2    Mark    HIV        Reactive  Reactive           Reactive    Reactive

id | Name | Test Name | CD4% | CD4 Lympo | CD4 Absolute
1    Mark   Immuno      12.0%  1299         838 


id | Name | Test Name | RPR    | TPHA
3    Carl    SY         Reactive  Reactive
```

Comment: You appear to be confused about something.  A result set has a well-defined set of columns -- whether the query is created dynamically or not.  Each row has the same columns.  You seem to be specifying a result set that has different columns for each row.

Comment: yes that what i meant.

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to all together like this. You can have one query pull for the HIV test, another for the Immuno test, and another for the SY test. But if you try to union them together you will get errors.

Comment: okay maybe its not possible to display all of them in one query, how can i do the query with specific test?

Comment: i have tried this `code`(if(tg.name='HIV', tc.name = 'EIA', tor.value = 'REACTIVE')then tor.value end) as EIA, (if(tg.name='HIV', tc.name = 'EIA2', tor.value = 'REACTIVE')then tor.value end) as EIA2,`code` and getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an effectively dynamic-column query like you're looking for requires shenanigans. The way I've done it before† is generally to use one crosstab/pivot query to capture the mapping between column *numbers* (of which you have up to some suitable maximum `N`) and final column *labels* for each entry. The output of this would be something like:

```
Test Name   |Test Performed |Index
HIV         |EIA            |1
HIV         |EIA2           |2
[…]
```

Then you have another query to map the other way, which comes out like this:

```
Test Name   |1      |2          |3              |4      |5
HIV         |EIA    |EIA2       |Rapid          |WB     |Final Kit
Immuno      |CD4%   |CD4 Lympo  |CD4 Absolute   |       |
SY          |RPR    |TPHA       |               |       |
```

Finally, you pivot on `Index` from the first map joined on `Test Name` and `Test Performed` from your initial table to generate the crosstab, and when you display the result, look up the column name/`Index` in the second map to get `Test Performed` back.

<sub>†Albeit *not* in either MySQL or C#. Transferrability is fun!</sub>

<sub>*I'll edit later to add sample SQL, once I dig it up and abstract it properly. This should get the general idea across for now, though.*</sub>

Comment: thank you i got your idea and came up with a solution.

Comment: @KevinRodriguez: Good deal! I'll still add some SQL later, though, just for posterity's sake. Or you could.